# How does the Vue render function differ from the template syntax?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template : '<App/>'
});
```

We know that the code specified as a template will only work if `runtimeCompiler` is `true`.

What I'm curious about is how the render function differs from the template syntax (it's hard to debug and look at the code TT).

Aren't template strings converted to JS code when precompiled in Vue?

Comment: You've answered your own question in your last comment. The template strings are compiled into render functions at build time to avoid having to do it at runtime. Build-time compilation also helps reduce bundle size by omitting the template compiler code.

Comment: A single file component, i.e. a `.vue` file, will be precompiled to replace the template with a `render` function. In theory other templates can be precompiled too but typically builds aren't configured to do that. As a result it is normal for the entry point to use `new Vue` with a `render` function rather than a template. In a typical SFC-based application that entry-point instance will be the only Vue instance that doesn't come from an SFC.

Comment: As a side note, whether you use `el: '#app'` or `.mount('#app')` is a separate consideration and is not relevant to whether you are using a template or a `render` function.

Comment: **tony19**,
**skirtle**,
**Delena Malan**
thanks.